# promised-mongo: can't finalize promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, promise

Here's a piece of code I'm working at: it saves reddit posts to mongoDB collection.

I'm using [promised-mongo](https://www.npmjs.com/package/promised-mongo) library

The problem is when the for loop completes and all data is saved to database, program does not exit, it continues executing doing nothing, despite of `done()` called at the end of each promised-mongo promise chain.

```
    for (var i = 0; i< posts.length; i++) { 
        posts[i].done = false;
        DB.posts.findOne({
            "id" : posts[i].id // it's 'id', not mongo's '_id'
        })
        .then(function(i) {
            return function(doc){
                if(doc) {
                    console.log('skipping')
                } else {
                    DB.posts.insert(posts[i]).then(function() {
                        console.log(arguments);
                        nSaved++;
                    });
                }
            }
        }(i))
        .catch(function(){
            console.log(arguments)
        })
        .done();
    }
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why do you think the program would need to exit "*when the for loop completes*"? There are still lots of open callbacks, each of them triggering another asynchronous action (`insert`) with its own callback.

Comment: Is this your whole program? What is `nSaved++` good for? What outputs do you get? Why are you calling `done()`?

Comment: Your node.js program won't close until you've closed the `MongoClient` connection pool (after all the updates complete). Are you doing that somewhere?

Comment: @JohnnyHK Correct! I forgot to close connection. However, I don't know how to correctly wait for _batch job_ to complete. I changed my code and added one more `then` that evaluates  `nSaved+nSkipped === nPlanned` and closes connection if it's true; is there any way to do it better?

Comment: @amdc You can use `Q.all` or `Q.allSettled` to coordinate the action to take once a set of promises has been fulfilled.  See [here](https://github.com/kriskowal/q#combination).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a few problems here:

- You are creating several promises in a `for` loop, but not keeping track of them
- You have a `DB.posts.insert` that creates a promise, but you are not awaiting it

To address them in reverse order:

If you don't return the promise created by `DB.posts.insert` there will be no way of awaiting it until it is done. You need to return it:

```
return function(doc){
    if(doc) {
        console.log('skipping')
    } else {
        // here
        return DB.posts.insert(posts[i]).then(function() {
            console.log(arguments);
            nSaved++;
        });
    }
}
```

And you also need to keep track of all the promises you are creating, so that you know when they are all done. An easy way to do this is to use `.map()` to map them to an array of promises, and then use `Promise.all()` to await them.

Assuming that `posts` is an array:

```
function ensurePost(post) {
    post.done = false;

    return DB.posts.findOne({
        "id" : post.id // it's 'id', not mongo's '_id'
    })
    .then(function(doc){
        if(doc) {
            console.log('skipping ' + post.id)
        } else {
            return DB.posts.insert(post).then(function() {
                console.log(arguments);
                nSaved++;
            });
        }
    })
    .catch(function(error){
        console.error('Error inserting', post.id, error);
    });
}

Promise.all(posts.map(ensurePost))
.done(function () {
    // all done. close the connection
});
```

This also eliminates the need for that unpleasant IIFE you had there.

Comment: Thank you very much! The initial problem was solved by @JohnnyHK in comments to original post, but I needed this feedback. I still don't completely understand promises, but it helped a bit :)